# Query Error and Loading the result Query to new Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody correct me with the below query where the query is going wrong ?
For the below Query i need to add where clause and get based on client names. When i execute the query i am able to view only first client data. And also  i want the result to store in separate database.

```
select  amount,[Account #]as cdn#,[CC ACCT]as CC#,[CardType] as CCType 
  from [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[VendorFiles] as a
  inner join [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] as d
  on d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),a.client)
Union all
  Select [Amount],[CDN #] as cdn#,[Card_No] as CC#,[Card_Type] as CCType 
  from [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[VirtualFiles] as b
  left join [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] as d
  on d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),b.[Client_Id])
  union all
  select [SV10_Amt] as Amount,[Cdr_Id] as cdn#,[SV07_Last4] as CC#,[CardType] as CCType
  from [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[IVRFiles] as c
  left join [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] as d
  on d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),c.[SV03_Clientnbr])
  where PK_Client in ('SWMC600',' SQMC203',' SQMC600',' SBMC203',' SBMC600',
' PROV203',' PROV600',' SWRC203',' SWRC600',' SMCC203',' SMCC600',' SWIS203',' SWIS600')
```

Can anybody help me with the above query where the query is going wrong and how to get the result for all clients in Where clause and how to store the result in separate database ?
Please write me a complete query for the above task....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I am not able to fetch data for all Client names, So can you tel me where exactly the query going wrong

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: IN operator is not working for the Query..

Comment: You have a space in front of every client id except the first.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure, but you have a space preceding each CLIENT ID except for the first one:

```
where PK_Client in ('SWMC600',' SQMC203',' SQMC600',' SBMC203',' SBMC600',
    ' PROV203',' PROV600',' SWRC203',' SWRC600',' SMCC203',' SMCC600',
    ' SWIS203',' SWIS600')
```

Just remove the spaces:

```
where PK_Client in ('SWMC600','SQMC203','SQMC600','SBMC203','SBMC600',
    'PROV203','PROV600','SWRC203','SWRC600','SMCC203','SMCC600',
    'SWIS203','SWIS600')
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause only works for the last select. Maybe you want it this way.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT  [Amount]
        , [Account #]as cdn#
        , [CC ACCT]as CC#
        , [CardType] as CCType 
        , PK_Client
    FROM [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[VendorFiles] AS a
    INNER JOIN [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] AS d
      ON d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),a.client)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Amount]
        , [CDN #] AS cdn#
        , [Card_No] AS CC#
        , [Card_Type] AS CCType 
        , PK_Client
    FROM [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[VirtualFiles] AS b
    LEFT JOIN [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] as d
        ON d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),b.[Client_Id])
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [SV10_Amt] AS Amount
        , [Cdr_Id] AS cdn#
        , [SV07_Last4] AS CC#
        , [CardType] AS CCType
        , PK_Client
    FROM [PayPal_staging].[dbo].[IVRFiles] AS c
    LEFT JOIN [CUBS].[dbo].[Client] AS d
        ON d.PK_Client=CONVERT(varchar(250),c.[SV03_Clientnbr])
) t
WHERE t.PK_Client IN ('SWMC600','SQMC203','SQMC600','SBMC203','SBMC600'
,'PROV203','PROV600','SWRC203','SWRC600','SMCC203','SMCC600'
,'SWIS203','SWIS600');
```